# Weird output on recursive QuickSort

Tags: recursion, bit-manipulation, quicksort, xor

I'm trying to implement a recursive quicksort in C that does all swapping by using bitwise XOR operations. Here is what I've got so far:

```
//bitwise recursive quicksort 
void quicksort(int *int_array,int p, int r){
    if(p<r){
            int q = part(int_array, p, r);
            quicksort(int_array,p, q-1);
            quicksort(int_array, q+1, r);
    }
}
//Partition 
int part(int *int_array, int p, int r){
    int pivot = int_array[r];
    int i = p-1;
    int j;
    for(j = p; j<=r-1; j++){
            if(int_array[j] <= pivot){
                    i++;
                    int_array[i] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];
                    int_array[j] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];
                    int_array[i] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];

            }
    }
    int_array[i+1] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
    int_array[r] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
    int_array[i+1] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
    return i+1;
}
```

When I run this code on an array of 20 ints, 19 out of 20 of them get changed to 0. Any idea why? I can't see anything wrong with the XOR swapping. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The XOR swap algorithm doesn't work when swapping an item with itself, because any number XORed with itself will be 0, the algorithm relies on there being two locations. So after the first line you have just wiped the value.

[XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

> However, the algorithm fails if x and y use the same storage location, since the value stored in that location will be zeroed out by the first XOR instruction, and then remain zero; it will not be "swapped with itself". Note that this is not the same as if x and y have the same values. The trouble only comes when x and y use the same storage location, in which case their values must already be equal.

You can just put a test around your swaps to make sure you never try swapping an element with itself:

```
int part(int *int_array, int p, int r){
    int pivot = int_array[r];
    int i = p-1;
    int j;
    for(j = p; j<=r-1; j++){
            if(int_array[j] <= pivot){
                    i++;
                    if(i != j) // avoid XORing item with itself
                    {
                        int_array[i] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];
                        int_array[j] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];
                        int_array[i] = int_array[i] ^ int_array[j];
                    }
            }
    }
    if(i+1 != r) // avoid XORing item with itself
    {
        int_array[i+1] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
        int_array[r] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
        int_array[i+1] = int_array[i+1] ^ int_array[r];
    }
    return i+1;
}
```